# OrientDB error on query date

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I've this table with these fields:

```
MyTable
code STRING
fromDate DATE
toDate DATE
```

The content of this table is the following:

```
'ABC', '2016-05-01 00:00:00', '2016-05-31 00:00:00'
'DEF', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '2099-01-01 00:00:00'
'GHI', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '2099-01-01 00:00:00'
```

If I try to write this query:

```
SELECT FROM MyTable WHERE fromDate <= '2016-05-01'
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT FROM MyTable WHERE fromDate <= DATE('2016-05-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

The result is the following:

```
'DEF', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '2099-01-01 00:00:00'
'GHI', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '2099-01-01 00:00:00'
```

So, OrientDB doesn't return the row with equal condition on date. Where's my fault?

Orient version I've used is **2.2.0**

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced your problem, could you open an issue on github ? Alternatively you could use SELECT FROM MyTable WHERE '2016-05-01' >= fromDate

Comment: I try to open on GitHub this critical bug. I don't understand how changing the order of factor on condition, that's ok

Comment: @AlessandroRota: Open on GitHub the issue: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OrientDB team the notice is arrive this bug has closed and will be released on 2.2.5 version

Go [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6389)